# AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'ctypes_support'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, numba

When attempting to `import numba` in Anaconda 5.0 installation of Python 3.6 (x64 on Win 10), I receive an error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'ctypes_support'
```

`numba` [package v0.36](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.36.1/index.html) seems to have installed without any hurdles.

Has anyone seen and been able to overcome this?

The full log is

```
>>> import numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .special import typeof, prange
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\special.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .parfor import prange
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\parfor.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numba import array_analysis, postproc, typeinfer
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\array_analysis.py", line 26, in <module>
    from numba.extending import intrinsic
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\extending.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .pythonapi import box, unbox, reflect, NativeValue
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\numba\pythonapi.py", line 12, in <module>
    import numba.ctypes_support as ctypes
AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'ctypes_support'
```

Comment: did you get the solution?